# Any question bank of Rewriting sentences without changing the meaning

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I am having Grammar exam in a week so I am looking for nay reference on a collection of large number of questions like rewriting sentences without changing the meaning, etc.

Our textbook is not good enough so asking for help here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for resources. That said, you may be interested in [the meta-question on good resources for leaning English](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available-online/2577#2577).

Answer (score 1):

Much of the literature on transformational grammar concerns the analysis of paraphrase, because transformations were held to change sentences in ways that did not affect meaning.  Look at McCawley, **The Syntactic Phenomena of English**, for instance, for the account of Extraposition ("That Lois left surprised me" -> "It surprised me that Lois left"), Passive ("Lois ate lots of pie" -> "Lots of pie was eaten by Lois"), Relative Clause Formation ("I planted an acorn, and it grew into an oak" -> "An acorn that I planted grew into an oak"), and so on.

(I'm not sure that McCawley discusses Relative Clause Formation under this name.)

Comment: It is not available in my country plus ebook versions are not available as well. Can you suggest something of similar quality but wider availability. It would be a great help.

Comment: I can't suggest anything of similar quality, because McCawley's book is very good (though not easy reading).  Also because I haven't been teaching syntax for a while.  Perhaps others will have suggestions.  You could do a web search on "transformational grammar introduction", and Wikipedia has an entry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformational_grammar

Comment: Here is [a list of transformations, with examples](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf), but without much discussion. All of these exist, and none of them change the meaning, but they are quite idiomatic, with lots of exceptions and special conditions for application.